# How to search/replace a range of words

Tags: search, replace, range, text-files

I want to replace a txt that could look something like this:

```
y1991<-cbind(data.frame(Depth_m$X, Depth_m$Y, BotTemp$y1991_7_te, BotSal$y1991_7_sa, PSIsobarst$y1991_7_so,
SurfSaline$y1991_7_so, SurfHeight$y1991_7_so, SurfTSST$y1991_7_so, Depth_m$Depth))
names(y1991)<-proj_names
y1991[] <- lapply(y1991, function(x){replace(x, x == 0, NA)})
y1991<-na.omit(y1991)
```

I have data for more than sixty years, so i want the same code, just with 1992, 1993, 1994 ect. replacing 1991, so it looks like this with for example 1992:

> y1992<-cbind(data.frame(Depth_m$X, Depth_m$Y, BotTemp$y1992_7_te,
>   BotSal$y1992_7_sa, PSIsobarst$y1992_7_so, SurfSaline$y1992_7_so,
>   SurfHeight$y1992_7_so, SurfTSST$y1992_7_so, Depth_m$Depth))
>   names(y1992)<-proj_names y1992[] <- lapply(y1992,
>   function(x){replace(x, x == 0, NA)}) y1992<-na.omit(y1992)

I have been looking hard on the internet for an answer, but so far ive found nothing. Hope you can help.
Jeppe

edit:
I found a solution, but it only gives me the printout, not a file i can save, but here goes:

```
X<-'y1991<-cbind(data.frame(Depth_m$X, Depth_m$Y, BotTemp$y1991_7_te, BotSal$y1991_7_sa, PSIsobarst$y1991_7_so,
    SurfSaline$y1991_7_so, SurfHeight$y1991_7_so, SurfTSST$y1991_7_so, Depth_m$Depth))
    names(y1991)<-proj_names'
for(xn in 1991:2010) {
Y <- gsub("1991", xn, X)
print(Y, quote=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific. What language are you working in? Are you trying to find and replace text in your code, or in a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Use any language you are comfortable in and generate a text string of such data. Start with a loop from 19xx to 20xx for 60 years and if its just numbers you want to replace then the code only has to replace numbers with the value from loop iterator.
Let me know which language you can program in and I will try to write something for you. All you need to know is

1. How to create a variable
2. How to loop using any conditional loop for example for loop
3. How to do string concatination and may be how to cast integer to a string
4. How to append string to output or to a file

if you are familiar with excel it is also possible to do this in excel and then copy paste in a text file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can do some programming in R, and is quite familiar with Excel, so any of those two would work for me.

Comment: Do note that while looking for 19XX, it might be important to ensure that it is preceeded by "y" and followed by a non-digit too.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems your search and replace requirement is very simple. You could simply scan through the text and do the replacement, couldn't you? Am I misunderstanding your requirement?

If you wish to use a regular expression, search for "y19" followed by exactly two digits and replace the matches with "y1992". E.g. if using Java:

String input = "....your string..";
String output = input.replaceAll(""y19\d{2}([^\d])", "y1992$1");

Note String#replaceAll() is a shortcut to java.util.regex.Matcher#replaceAll()
If you are running the same regex multiple times first creating the "Pattern" and then matching will be more efficient.

Comment: I am not familiar with Java at all, but thank you for the reply.

Comment: Well the regex should be similar in other languages too.

Comment: In the replacement text "y1992$1" the "$1" means the first matched group the one in parenthesis in the regex (which would be the non-digit). In some languages the syntax maybe \1 instead of $1.